# Freeform is unable to send emails after changing webhost

Tags: plugin-freeform

I have moved a website to a new webhost. Since the freeform ist no able to send any emails for notification reasons or alert reasons. Is there a basic switch or something similar I am missing to enable sending emails?

Comment: If you go to Settings > Emails, what is Transport Type set to?

Comment: Also worth giving these a read-through: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/troubleshooting-email-errors and https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/why-doesnt-craft-send-emails

Comment: @tommysvr transport type is sendmail. Testing fails: "an error while testing the email settings ..." I tried gmail, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, it's likely that Sendmail isn't configured on your new host. You could contact them for help in setting that up, though I'd recommend considering a switch to sending via SMTP/API. There's a bunch of different services out there, many of which have free tiers if you're not sending many emails - SendGrid, Mandrill, Amazon SES are a few options available.